# Need to get clusters visible at a particular zoom level only

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have created marker clusters for marker

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(propertiesData[i][1], propertiesData[i][2]),
    map: map
    ....
  });

var myOptions = {
    boxStyle: {
        marginTop:-60+'px'
    }
};

markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,markerClustererOptions);
```

Till this I am able to work and show cluster.

Now I want to apply a check on zoom changed event where I need to get all visible clusters at that zoom level.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
  // NEED TO GET ALL  VISIBLE CLUSTERS HERE
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do that with the `Max zoom level` setting in the `MarkerClusterer`.

As it is shown in [this demo,](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/advanced_example.html) if you set the `Max zoom level` to 7, then when user zoom in to zoom level 8, `MarkerClusterer` would stop clustering the markers.
[image]

Comment: I think I might have stated the question incorrectly. I meant at a particular zoom level., some clusters are visible. Can you please tell me which ones are visible at that time.